# Android: Room can't access member variable when using getter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to access a member variable of my `entity` which is defined with a custom getter inside my `query`. My problem is, that I can't access the setter in my `@Query()` when I declare my variable as a `val`. Does this have to do with the fact, that there is no backing field when using `val`?

### Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "products")
data class ProductCacheEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val name: String = "",
    val price: Float = 0F,
    val optionalServicePricing: Float = 0F,
    val optionalServiceNote: String = "",
    val category: String = "",
    val note: String = "",
    var articelNumber: Int = 0,
    val quantity: Int = 1,
    val images: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf(),
    val description: ArrayList<ProductDescription> = arrayListOf(),
    val technicalDescription: ArrayList<ProductDescription>? = arrayListOf(),
    val hasAccessories: Boolean = false
)
```

### Not Working

```
// Not working with private set
var combinedPrice: Float = 0.0f
    get() = if (serviceWanted) price + optionalServicePricing else price
    private set

@Query("SELECT SUM(combinedPrice * quantity) FROM products")
fun getSummedPrice(): LiveData<Float>
```

### Not Working

```
val combinedPrice: Float
    get() = if (serviceWanted) price + optionalServicePricing else price

@Query("SELECT SUM(combinedPrice * quantity) FROM products") // unresolved reference combinedPrice
fun getSummedPrice(): LiveData<Float>
```

### Stacktrace

```
C:\Users\Censored\AndroidStudioProjects\Censored\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\Censored\app\framework\datasource\models\product\ProductCacheEntity.java:14: error: Cannot find setter for field.
    private float combinedPrice = 0.0F;
```

Comment: This is because code in the second example does not generate a bytecode backing field for combinedPrice.

Comment: @m0skit0 then which alternative should I use? I can't write `private set` because then my code does not compile (`cannot find setter`). But I don't want anybody to change this value

Comment: You said it works with private set. From where are you setting the value? Or is it Room that's giving this error?

Comment: I was wrong, but deleting the `private set` helped. But this is not really what I wanted, because now everyone can manipulate my `combinedPrice` value

Comment: Can you give more details about what error private set shows?

Comment: @m0skit0 Added stacktrace

Comment: What about private var and then exposing a fun that sets the combinedPrice?

Comment: As said, **I** don't set the combinedPrice value, it is computed as `price + optionalServicePrice`

Comment: Sounds like you need a wrapper class that you map the class to. Room needs a public getter/setter to be able to read/write the values to

Comment: Well then a fun that returns combinedPrice :p